# How to logout specific security domain virtual user from sitecore

Tags: sitecore-api, multisite, authentication, virtual-user

I am creating virtual user for site 1 using below code

```
AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("site1\\"+Email, true);
```

for site 2 using below code

```
AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("site2\\"+Email, true);
```

Now I want to logout user from site specific.
Currently using below code

```
AuthenticationManager.Logout();
Sitecore.Context.User.Delete();
```

This will logout and delete user from site1 and site2. But I want to logout from specific site and delete from specific site

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your code inside the below `using` statement to see if it helps:

```
 using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(website))
{
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Hi Site context is coming corructly using Sitecore.Context.Site. but Sitecore.Context.User is not coming corructly based on site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solutions to make it work. The first approach you can try is using `UserSwitcher` using the below code.

```
using (new UserSwitcher("domain\\username"))
{
    // your code here
}
```

The second approach you can use is to get the currently active user and then use the `AuthenticationManager.Logout()` to log out the user using the below code.

```
var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.GetActiveUser();
virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Clear();
virtualUser.Roles.RemoveAll();
virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.Save();
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Logout();
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: I want to logout specific domain virtual user not all the active users. the current code which you explained is already using and not working as expected

Comment: So did you try to add the code under UserSwitcher? @shahul

Comment: It is not working @sumit